# Get number inside and outsite () sign

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a string

```
$string = "10(400)";
preg_match_all('#[:0-9]([:0-9])#', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I try to get

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 400 )
```

How to do that thank, I'm is newer with preg thanks

Comment: Why `40` and not `400`?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes it's 400, i typing wrong sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take all numbers in a string you can use [`\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/iN6hH6/1):

```
$string = "10(400)";
preg_match_all('#\d+#', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Check the [working fiddle here.](http://ideone.com/LuNkP8)

---

The `\d` in regex is the same as `[0-9]` which means it will match *one* digit. When you combine it with the plus sign `+` it means that all nested digits will be grouped in one match.

As the `preg_match_all` will search all matches (obviously).. you do not need to specify the `g` flag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you explain more about that for perfect thanks :)

Comment: @DeLe. Done, hope it helped.